# Get day after 30 days

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get date after 30 days from current date. I tried below code:

```
var time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate()+30);
```

**Output is:**

```
Sun Feb 21 2016 18:11:27 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

When I try to get day it gives me 0, I used `time.getDay()`.
`time.getMonth()` and `time.getFullYear()` work perfectly.

How do I get day from above date?

Comment: You need to use `.getDate()` to get the date value... `.getDay()` gives the day of the week value where 0 is the sunday

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny now i am getting what i want.

Comment: I would try with moment.js it is a very clear an easy library that works with many localizations and date formats

Comment: @juangarcia i know about moment.js, but for now i don't want to increase size of my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Date.getDate() to get the [day of the month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) will return the day of the week value

```js
var time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate() + 30);
var day = time.getDate();
document.body.innerHTML = 'The date is: ' + day;
```

Answer (score 1):

`getDay()` gives you the day of the week, `0` means Sunday.

Use `getDate()` for the day of the month.

Here's a [getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) reference.

Here's a [getDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) reference.